# how to read all the properties of all the files in a Document Set Using @pnp spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, reactjs

how to read all the properties of  all the files in a Document Set  Using @pnp spfx React JS ?

Comment: what have you tried so far and/or what is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DocumentSet is just a folder with a specialized Content Type.  To get all the files in a DocumentSet or Folder you need to use one of the methods to get a folder reference (e.g. `getFolderById`, `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl`, etc.), and get the `files` collection.  To get item metadata for each of those files all in a single REST API call, add an `expand("ListItemAllFields")`, then every returned `file` will also have all metadata.

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/testsite/docsetslib/randomdocset').files.expand("ListItemAllFields").get().then((files) => {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        let fileProperties = file.ListItemAllFields;
    });
});
```